# Canceling Task Delay in .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I am currently trying to implement a substitute for .Net 4.5's `Task.Delay()` method in a program that must target .Net 4.0.  I found the following code at [this blog](http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.com/2012/06/async-taskdelay.html).

```
    /* You can write Task-based asynchronous methods by utilizing a TaskCompletionSource.
A TaskCompletionSource gives you a 'slave' Task that you can manually signal.
Calling SetResult() signals the task as complete, and any continuations kick off. */

void Main()
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        Task task = Delay (2000);
        task.ContinueWith (_ => "Done".Dump());
    }
}

Task Delay (int milliseconds)        // Asynchronous NON-BLOCKING method
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    new Timer (_ => tcs.SetResult (null)).Change (milliseconds, -1);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

`Tasks` are fairly new to me.  `System.Threading.Timer` and `TaskCompletionSource` are brand new to me (as of today), and I'm struggling a bit with them.  All that aside, I'm wondering how I might add `CancellationToken` functionality to this code.  I'm assuming I could add a parameter to the `Delay()` method like this:

```
Task Delay (int milliseconds, CancellationToken token)        // Asynchronous NON-BLOCKING method
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    new Timer (_ => tcs.SetResult (null)).Change (milliseconds, -1);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

... but then, where do I put the logic for checking the token and getting out of the method?  Somewhere in the callback?  Is this even possible?

Comment: Microsoft provides a NuGet package [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) which backports many of the added 4.5 features to 4.0. You can access delay via `TaskEx.Delay()` if you have the package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried to change your code as little as possible but here is a working example that behaves in the same way as Task.Delay.

It's important to note that I use `TrySetCanceled` and `TrySetResult` because the Timer could finish after the task is canceled. Ideally you want to stop the timer.

Also note a canceled task will throw a **TaskCanceledException**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // A cancellation source that will cancel itself after 1 second
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    try
    {
        // This will only wait 1 second because as it will be cancelled.
        Task t = Delay(5000, cancellationTokenSource.Token);                
        t.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("The task completed");
    }
    catch (AggregateException exception)
    {
        // Expecting a TaskCanceledException
        foreach (Exception ex in exception.InnerExceptions)
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static Task Delay(int milliseconds, CancellationToken token)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    token.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled());
    Timer timer = new Timer(_ => tcs.TrySetResult(null));
    timer.Change(milliseconds, -1);            
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Reading a bit more into your question. If you need Task.Delay and you're targeting .NET 4.0 then you should use the Microsoft Async nuget package from http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/ it contains the method `TaskEx.Delay`

Comment: This is a great two-fold answer.  I actually already had Microsoft.Bcl.Async installed in my project, but I didn't realize they were hiding those methods under TaskEx.  Thanks for both the long-hand explanation of context and the tip on the BCL extension.

Comment: Initializing a CancellationTokenSource with a timeout isn't possible in .NET 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Like [this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationToken.cs,188):

```
token.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCancelled());
```

Comment: Where does that go in context?  Forgive me if this seems obvious, there are several newish concepts for me here.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are a version that prevents disposal of timer by the garbage collector

```
    public static Task Delay(int milliseconds, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        var timer = new OneShotTimer((t) => {
            using ((OneShotTimer)t)
                tcs.SetResult(null);
        });
        token.Register(() => {
            if (timer.TryCancel())
            {
                using (timer)
                    tcs.SetCanceled();
            }
        });
        timer.Start(milliseconds);
        return tcs.Task;
    }


    public class OneShotTimer : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly object sync = new object();
        private readonly TimerCallback oneShotCallback;
        private readonly Timer timer;
        private bool isActive;

        public OneShotTimer(TimerCallback oneShotCallback, int dueTime = Timeout.Infinite)
        {
            this.oneShotCallback = oneShotCallback;
            this.isActive = dueTime != Timeout.Infinite;
            this.timer = new Timer(callback, this, dueTime, Timeout.Infinite);
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            timer.Dispose();
        }


        public void Start(int dueTime)
        {
            if (!tryChange(true, dueTime))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The timer has already been started");
        }


        public bool TryCancel()
        {
            return tryChange(false, Timeout.Infinite);
        }


        public bool tryChange(bool targetIsActive, int dueTime)
        {
            bool result = false;
            lock (sync)
            {
                if (isActive != targetIsActive)
                {
                    result = true;
                    isActive = targetIsActive;
                    timer.Change(dueTime, Timeout.Infinite);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }


        private static void callback(object state)
        {
            var oneShotTimer = (OneShotTimer)state;
            if (oneShotTimer.TryCancel())
                oneShotTimer.oneShotCallback(oneShotTimer);
        }
    }
```